# Unusual routes from UK to Denmark

Tags: uk, denmark

My wife and I are going to Denmark soon.  The original plan was to fly out and return by train.  We booked a flight with SAS from Birmingham to Copenhagen but it was cancelled.  Now we have a booking with BA from Heathrow to Copenhagen but, considering the news of strikes and cancellations, I would like to make a contingency plan.  If I am going to do this then I'd like something a bit different.  My first step was to check the Harwich to Esbjerg ferry which I have used in the past.  Unfortunately, this no longer operates.

What are my options?  No vehicle, just two adults.

Comment: I was going to recommend the Newcastle-Bergen ferry but sadly that's now only a fond memory.

Comment: seat61 (https://www.seat61.com/Denmark.htm) gives an overview of the possibilities, both all-train and train+ferry.

Comment: @MichaelKay I had big hope that they would re-open that line after Brexit (what with UK and Norway having now kind of similar status and a special bilateral trade deal and all), but no. Sad indeed.

Comment: American here. That's like, New York to Chicago with a tunnelferry.  For such a short distance, just drive it :)

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica According to google NY - Chicago is more than 5 hours shorter

Comment: I  am not considering driving.  I have done it in the past.  Depending on the requirements, it can make sense but less often these days than it used to be.  In this case, 2 people with little luggage and wanting a relaxing trip, driving does not qualify.

Comment: Some suggestions from [Seat 61](https://www.seat61.com/Denmark.htm)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I live in Denmark but am from the UK. My usual route is to fly Ryanair from Stanstead to Aalborg. The bonus is it's often very cheap (less than £10 for a single-way ticket!) If you want to get to Copenhagen after that you can book tickets on Flixbus or DSB trains (about 5 hours in either case)

Of course, it's still flying. But not with SAS, and to a different destination. The DSB train goes through all of the Danish countryside and has some lovely views from the two rail bridges between the Danish islands (some of the bridges are mind-bogglingly long!)

Comment: That will be a good back up plan.  I have been to that side of Denmark but my wife has not.

Comment: Aalborg is the furthest possible airport. Aarhus (Stansted), Billund (Stansted, Manchester), and Copenhagen(!) (Stansted, Manchester) are much closer.

Comment: @StrangerToKindness Manchester-Billund used to be interesting in that the British Airways-branded service was operated by a 32-seat Dornier 328JET, which would make a change from the typical 737 or A320. It's still listed as such on flightmapper.net but there are no flights under the listed codes on flightradar24 in the next or last week, so I guess it's not currently running.

Comment: I'm not sure how flying Ryanair is going to be any better or less susceptible to cancellations/delays than flying SAS or BA.

Comment: @FreeMan The other day BA announced the cancellation of a further 1500 flights. SAS is heavily hit by strikes. Ryanair isn't doing any of that,

Comment: @StrangerToKindnesss The extra distance is not a problem as it will be extra distance in a new (to my wife) area.  This is pretty much what I hoped for.  A bit slower and more complex than a direct flight to Copenhagen but not ridiculously so.  Also interstingly different.

Comment: @Freeman This is a backup plan,  if BA don't cancel then we will use them but, as StrangerToKindness says, it is not inconceivable that BA will cancel maybe with little notice.

Answer (score 23):

Bicycle along the [Eurovelo 12 route](https://en.eurovelo.com/ev12).

This long distance cycle route is called the North Sea route. It starts in Scotland, goes down the East cost of the UK, then along the French, Belgian, Dutch, German, Danish and Norwegian coastlines.

If you could get to Calais or Dunkirk there is a remarkably easy and pleasant journey ahead of you. The route is well marked, flat, and almost exclusively on purpose built, vehicle free cycle tracks.

The distance is around 900km from Calais to Denmark, so it will take you a few days but the journey *is* the adventure.

[image: Eurovelo 12 route]

Comment: My brother-in-law is doing that one.  I need to get fit again before I attempt it.

Comment: What if the OP has luggage?

Comment: A warning from someone who has done long bike trips in the past: 900km for someone who is not used to long biking will be more than "a few days". This needs a certain level of preparation and equipment.

Comment: One brother-in-law did this many years ago and another is about to try.  He is preparing carefully.

Answer (score 14):

This would be different:

- [train](https://ojp.nationalrail.co.uk/service/timesandfares/Birmingham/NCL/210722/0800/dep) from Birmingham (or wherever) > Newcastle
- [DFDS Ferry](https://www.dfds.com/en-gb/passenger-ferries/ferry-crossings/ferries-to-holland/newcastle-amsterdam) from Newcastle > Amsterdam
- [train](https://www.seat61.com/international-trains/trains-from-Amsterdam.htm#Amsterdam-Copenhagen) from Amsterdam > Copenhagen

This will require bus or taxi at each end of the ferry trip, but the ferry itself is overnight.

Comment: There are buses between the train stations and the ferry ports, taxis will be rather expensive, the Dutch taxi ride may cost as much as your train ticket from Amsterdam to Denmark.

Comment: Thanks.  That looks worth considering.  As I said to Hilmar, my wife won't want a long distance bus but local buses are fine.

Comment: From Birmingham, I'd have thought it'd be much more convenient/faster to get the train to Harwich for the ferry to Hoek van Holland?

Comment: For both Harwich-Hook and Newcastle-Amsterdam overnight journies are the most likely or only options. The day ferry from Harwich is early enough that getting there by train on that day is unlikely. Just look at the overal cost and timings.

Comment: Note that the ferry to Amsterdam doesn't actually go to Amsterdam. It goes to Ijmuiden. From the ferry terminal to Amsterdam Centraal station, you either take two busses, or walk + bus to either Haarlem station or Amsterdam Sloterdijk station, from which you take a train to Amsterdam Centraal. (See [9292.nl](https://9292.nl/en)).

Comment: @Willeke - Tomorrow: Stena Lines 2 sailings daily from Harwich: (1) check in by 08:15 sail 09:00 arrive Hook 17:15 (2) check in by 22:15 sail 23:00 arrive Hook 08:00. First train from Liverpool Street to Harwich International (Ferry terminal) 06:00 arrive 07:18. Last train to get night sailing depart Liverpool Street 20:00 arrive Harwich 21:18. Usually change at Manningtree.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, travel from anywhere beyond London and how do you catch a 6 AM train from London?

Comment: @Abigail, or you catch the coach the ferry company arranges upon arrival.

Comment: @Willeke - When I do this from Bristol I stay in a Comfort Inn or Travelodge overnight.

Comment: Hull to Rotterdam overnight (P&O) might also be an option? I haven't checked whether the connections between ferry port and rail station are any better or worse than Newcastle/Amsterdam.

Answer (score 5):

Try https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Birmingham-England/Copenhagen

This will give you multiple options with only trains and/or busses. Trains will be expensive and he quickest one is 17 hours. Busses may be cheaper but also substantially longer and in general less comfortable.

You may have to stitch individual legs together but looking at a 30 hour bus route you probably want to break it up anyway.

Comment: I am very happy to rough it.  My wife is not overly fussy but she won't like a long distance bus.  The site looks useful though, thanks.

Comment: (+1) Not worth a separate answer but for trains, especially to and from the UK, you could add https://www.seat61.com/Denmark.htm

Answer (score 4):

You can do the entire trip by train. [This site](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Birmingham-England/Copenhagen) gives a travel time of 17h45m using five different trains:

- Birmingham - London
- London - Brussels
- Brussels - Cologne
- Cologne - Hamburg
- Hamburg - Copenhagen

Alternative train options via Paris and Amsterdam exist as well.

Comment: That, in reverse, is approximately our trip home.  We plan to take our time with breaks in Hamburg etc.